Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed - AWS Lambda failure message
{     "errorType": "TargetCloseError",     "errorMessage": "Protocol
error
(Page.navigate): Target closed",     "name": "TargetCloseError",     "cause": {         "errorType": "ProtocolError",         "errorMessage": "",         "name": "ProtocolError",         "stack": [             "ProtocolError",             "    at <instance_members_initializer> (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:42:14)",             "    at new Callback (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:46:16)",             "    at CallbackRegistry.create (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:86:26)",             "    at Connection._rawSend (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:208:26)",             "    at CdpCDPSession.send (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/CDPSession.js:62:33)",             "    at navigate (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Frame.js:164:51)",             "    at CdpFrame.goto (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Frame.js:142:17)",             "    at CdpFrame. (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/decorators.js:108:27)",             "    at CdpPage.goto (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/api/Page.js:724:43)",             "    at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:38:18)"        ]     },     "stack": [         "TargetCloseError: Protocol
error
(Page.navigate): Target closed",         "    at CallbackRegistry.clear (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:139:36)",         "    at CdpCDPSession._onClosed (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/CDPSession.js:97:25)",         "    at #onClose (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:285:21)",         "    at WebSocket. (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/NodeWebSocketTransport.js:57:30)",         "    at callListener (/var/task/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:290:14)",         "    at WebSocket.onClose (/var/task/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:220:9)",         "    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:517:28)",         "    at WebSocket.emitClose (/var/task/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:260:10)",         "    at Socket.socketOnClose (/var/task/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1272:15)",         "    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)"    ] }

Check Cloudwatch log
Lambda Version compatibility


Solution is,
On the latest Lambda Runtime configuration version are not good, the version having failure fixes.
My current node version is 18.X
And the Runtime Configuration version I set it as "Auto" thats why this issue occurs.
Remove the "Auto" and make it as "Manual" and add your last working Runtime Configuration Version.
You can get the last working runtime ARN from your CloudWatch Logs
